# javascript - when reading file, browser opens well but it is blank browser

Tags: javascript, html

My object: Take latitude, longitude columns from textfile(.txt) and mark them on googlemap api v3.

For the first step, I made a code for reading textfile by javascript and html. When I run this code, chrome and IE browser open well but nothing happened. javascript part don't work. How can I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fso=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var 
filename="C:\\text.txt";
    function savefile() {
        if (!fso.FileExists(filename)) {
            fso.CreateTextFile(filename,true);
        }
        var 
f=fso.OpenTextFile(filename,2,true);

f.Write(myarea.innerHTML);
        f.Close();
    }
    function loadfile() {

if (!fso.FileExists(filename)) {

fso.CreateTextFile(filename,true);

}
        var f=fso.OpenTextFile(filename,1);
        r=f.ReadAll();
        f.Close();
        myarea.innerHTML=r;
    }

function window.onload() {
        loadfile(filename);

}
</script>
<div id=myarea contenteditable=true 
style="width:320;height:240;border:solid 2 
inset;overflow:scroll;background-color:silver;"></div>
<br><input 
type=button value=load onclick=loadfile()><input type=button value=save 
onclick=savefile()>
</body>
</html>
```

text.txt => (delimiter = " ")

```
year class sex a b c d
1 1 f 90 80 60 100 
1 1 m 90 80 60 100 
1 2 f 90 70 60 100 
2 1 f 100 80 60 100 
3 1 m 90 99 60 100
```

Comment: What have you done to debug? Have you looked in the console to see if you're getting any errors?

Comment: You cannot read or write files in the local file system through front-end scripts like JavaScript. This is in order to avoid security risks to local file system.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use an external .js file (instead of a .txt file) to  contain your data. In the JS file, store the data in some data structure (like array or objects). You can refer that external JS file in your main code by accessing the array or object using variables and do whatever data manipulations you want to do. This is because, you cannot read or write data files in your local file system through JavaScript. Your OS will restrict this just to ensure security of your local file system. To be more clear, some third party site may use a script to write malicious file into your local file system if such restriction is not there.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have one question, JS file means JSON? I use python. so, I should save data in JSON or first in txt and then change it to JSON.